# Create over 1.5k files with php

Tags: php, file

So i want to run this script that will create around 1.5k files at once. But Not having so much success and the reason is it is only creating 5-10 files.

The reason being is because the script doesn't run long enough for it to create every file. Since im guessing file generation is async.

How can I do such a thing.

My code is the following.

```
try {
        $this->tmp_file_name = 'article' . md5(time());
        //-- open file
        $file = fopen($this->tmp_file_name, 'w');
        if (!$file) {
            throw new \ErrorException('Cannot create ' . $this->tmp_file_name . ' file!');
        }

        //-- write file
        $fwrite_result = fwrite($file, json_encode($data));
        if (!$fwrite_result) {
            throw new \ErrorException('Cannot create ' . $this->tmp_file_name . ' file!');
        }

        fclose($file);

        return true;
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        return false;
    }
```

Now this method is called over 1.5k times.

Comment: how many of the times it is called, does it return false?

Comment: No it does not because it will throw an exception if it will and none are shown in the browser.

Comment: may be it could help to set: set_time_limit(0); at top of your scrip, those setting is allowing your script to run for ever.

Comment: Have tried that, still doesn't work

Comment: What is `$this->tmp_file_name` for those 1.5K iterations?

Comment: That just points into a property to an object so another method adds it to a zip file.

Comment: Okay i have found the issue, its because of my file name it was being the same everytime.

Comment: @Colosuslol you're welcome :-)